# How to safegaurd AWS EC2 node based website from Spam and DDOS?

Tags: wordpress, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a website deployed on AWS EC2 running on ubuntu,Apache, MYSQL. We have been getting continous requestes from below IP 
"195.154.105.219"
"88.150.242.243". Requesting for xmlrpc.php file using POST method. As a result our website has become really slow and our clients work has been effected. As of now we have blocked these IP values by dropping them from iptables. We would like to know how to safegaurd our site from any future attacks like this.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general, and depending to your application's requirements, your budget and other factors, there are several techniques you can use, separately or together to mitigate DDOS and SPAM attacks.

- Use Auto Scaling and an Elastic Load Balancer, to let AWS scale your infrastructure depending on traffic : http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/
- Use S3 to serve static content.  S3 is designed is scaling automatically for incoming traffic.  All content served by S3 directly allows to offload your EC2 based web server : http://aws.amazon.com/s3/
- Use CloudFront to distribute and server your content from AWS' edge location.  This mitigates DDOS by distributing attackers' request to the network of edge locations instead of sending the traffic to your web server : http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

All these three options have a cost associated, be sure to understand the pricing structure before deciding to implement any of these.

If you have a relatively short and stable list of IP addresses you want to block, you can customise either your EC2 instance's Security Group (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) either your VPC Subnet ACL (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html) to deny traffic from these IP addresses.  This approach is not very scalable and, most of the time, you will play a mouse / cat game trying to catchup with whatever new addresses are used by your attackers

Last but not least, using plain old Apache configuration to block certain URL or restrict access to these by IP Addresses is very effective too (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require and File Directive)

Last but not least, I would encourage everyone to watch this re:invent talk about DDOS resiliency for AWS : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7vTPlV8P3U)

Seb

Answer (score 0):

`xmlrpc.php` is from wordpress. install the Disable xmlrpc pingback plugin, or better yet , in the wordpress site. .htaccess , deny xmlrpc.php file ;). that will fix it. Also checkup the `wp-admin/scripts` for any wierd script or just `. find /var/www/ -type f -mtime -10` , to find the latest modified files.. check for any wierd php script..